# How to resolve Duplicate column name error in MariaDb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to run the below query in HeidiSQL-

```
INSERT INTO entities (id, name, description, port) SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 1, 'customer', 'Customer', 'xyz') AS tmp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( SELECT name FROM entities WHERE name = 'customer' AND port = 'xyz' ) LIMIT 1
```

I want to insert the above values in `entities` table if not exists.
But I am getting this error-
`Duplicate column name 'Customer'`

Any idea how to resolve this?
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add aliases to the select oart of the query:

```
INSERT INTO entities (id, name, description, port) SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 1, 'customer' as name, 'Customer' as description, 'xyz') AS tmp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( SELECT name FROM entities WHERE name = 'customer' AND port = 'xyz' ) LIMIT 1
```

However, I would rather create a unique index on `name - port` fields, which would prevent duplicate records from being created.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note that the column 'id' is the primary key):

```
INSERT INTO entities (name, description, port) 
SELECT 'customer', 'Customer', 'xyz' FROM entities 
WHERE name NOT IN ( SELECT name FROM entities WHERE name = 'customer' AND port = 'xyz' ) LIMIT 1
```